# Attempting to implement the quicksort technique shown in the following video

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

**This is the video I am referring to:**
https://youtu.be/ywWBy6J5gz8

**This is the code that I have tried in python:**

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
 
    pivot = arr[low]
    i = low + 1
    j = high

    switch = True

    while (True):
        while switch == True:
            while arr[j] >= pivot and i < j:
                j -= 1
            pos = arr.index(pivot)
            arr[j] , arr[pos] = arr[pos], arr[j]
            switch = False

        while switch == False:
            while arr[i] <= pivot and i < j:
                i += 1
            pos2 = arr.index(pivot)
            arr[i] , arr[pos2] = arr[pos2], arr[i]
            switch = True

        if i >= j:
            return j
 

def quickSort(arr, low, high):

    if high - low >= 1:
        pivot = partition(arr, low, high)
        quickSort(arr, low, pivot - 1)
        quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, high)


arr = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 4]
quickSort(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)
print("Sorted array:")
print(arr)
```

**Output:**
Sorted array:
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7]

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: And what goes wrong?

Comment: Video-link as problem description is not good. Who knows how long the videos will exist.

Comment: Maybe use another tutorial? "partition" should ensure that the pivot element is moved to its final position and that all elements equal or less pivot are to the left (towards beginning of list) of pivot and those greater or equal on the right. "partition" doesn't do that. Details should be explained by a good tutorial.

Comment: It sorts correctly till the pivot is chosen to be 7. After 7, 4 is chosen to be the next pivot. And, it swaps 4 and 6's positions. such that 6 is to the left of 4 which it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- In the video the pivot is one of the two persons that are stepped forward, the one with the dark hat (without the light decoration). There is no third person in this process, yet you define `i` and `j` as separate indices from the index where the pivot resides. To harmonise your code with the video you should initialise `i` to `low`. The two persons that stepped forward represent `i` and `j` in your code.
- The partitioning should really end when `i >= j`, yet if this condition occurs in the first block, then the second block still executes and performs an undesired swap there. You should immediately exit the function when `i >= j`. If you code it like that, you don't need this `switch` anymore either.
- The call of `arr.index(pivot)` is not required, nor efficient, nor suggested by the video. You already *know* where the pivot is, as it is one of the two persons that are stepped forward (dark hat), so `i` or `j`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
    pivot = arr[low]
    i = low
    j = high

    while True:
        while arr[j] >= pivot:
            j -= 1
            if i >= j:
                return i
        arr[j], arr[i] = pivot, arr[j]
        while arr[i] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            if i >= j:
                return j
        arr[i], arr[j] = pivot, arr[i]
```

This now implements what is shown in the video.